# Powerapps - Split Collection into smaller Collections based on SQL lookup data

Tags: sql-server, powerapps, powerapps-collection

-=-=-=-=-

Edit #3

Okay, this is just baffling as heck.

I've narrowed this down to one single line...

A sample of my code, with three examples:

```
            ForAll(ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList,
              If(
//    line 1      (LookUp(Master_Transaction_Log, Result in Scan_Code).Scan_Code) in Result,
//    line 2      (LookUp(Master_Transaction_Log, "Comms Lockoff" in Transaction_Type).Scan_Code) in Result,
//    line 3      (LookUp(Master_Transaction_Log, "Comms Lockoff" in Transaction_Type And Result in Scan_Code).Scan_Code) in Result,
              Collect(SC_OnCommsHold,ThisRecord),
              Collect(SC_Remainder_1,ThisRecord));
            );
```

My database has *one single entry* that fits the above criteria.

When I uncomment only **line 1**, the routine runs great. SC_OnCommsHold receives one record, and SC_Remainder_1 gets the other three.

When I uncomment only **line 2**, the routine runs great. SC_OnCommsHold receives one record, and SC_Remainder_1 gets the other three.

When I uncomment only **line 3**, the result fails. SC_OnCommsHold receives no records. All records get piled into SC_Remainder_1

It seems to me like it's *got* to be some sort of logical error in line 3, but I an absolutely baffled.

-=-=-=-=-

Edit #2

The following sequence produces the result I'm looking for:

```
            ClearCollect(SC_OnCommsHold, ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList);
            ClearCollect(SC_Remainder_1, ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList);
            Clear(SC_OnCommsHold);
            Clear(SC_Remainder_1);
            ForAll(ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList,
              If(
                (LookUp(Master_Transaction_Log, Result in Scan_Code, Scan_Code)) in Result,
              Collect(SC_OnCommsHold,ThisRecord),
              Collect(SC_Remainder_1,ThisRecord));
            );
```

but the following sequence fails out (produces an empty Collection for SC_OnCommsHold):

```
            ClearCollect(SC_OnCommsHold, ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList);
            ClearCollect(SC_Remainder_1, ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList);
            Clear(SC_OnCommsHold);
            Clear(SC_Remainder_1);
            ForAll(ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList,
              If(
                (LookUp(Master_Transaction_Log, Result in Scan_Code && "Comms Lockoff" in Transaction_Type, Scan_Code)) in Result,
              Collect(SC_OnCommsHold,ThisRecord),
              Collect(SC_Remainder_1,ThisRecord));
            );
```

I have confirmed that there is in fact a data entry in Master_Transaction_Log that fits that criteria.

I assume my LookUp line needs to be better, but this is about as simple as I can imagine and it's still not working. Argh.

-=-=-=-=-

Edited for clarity #1 (I hope!):

The **Master_Transactions_Log** database is well over half a million entries, but my scans are typically under a hundred in count.

My four test entries (saved into **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList**) are:

```
REQ2069120.RITM2374312.01 
REQ2075966.RITM2382958.01 
REQ2081369.RITM2389938.01 
REQ2091095.RITM2402123.01
```

I have manually added a record into the SQL database (for testing purposes, and I *know* at this moment that there is only one single entry that matches this criteria) such that there is a *single record* where Scan_Code = "REQ2081369.RITM2389938.01" and Transaction_Type = "New Equipment Delivery - Comms Lockoff" (just trying to keep it simple right now)

The result should be two collections:

**SC_OnCommsHold** with a column called "Result_OnHold" which only contains a single entry:

```
REQ2081369.RITM2389938.01
```

**SC_Remainder_1** with a column called "Result" which contains all entries from ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList *minus entries that are now in SC_OnCommsHold*:

```
REQ2069120.RITM2374312.01 
REQ2075966.RITM2382958.01 
REQ2091095.RITM2402123.01
```

My code at-the-moment is:

```
ClearCollect(SC_OnCommsHold, RenameColumns(ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList,"Result","Result_OnHold"));
ClearCollect(SC_Remainder_1, ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList);
//RemoveIf(SC_OnCommsHold, "REQ2081369.RITM2389938.01" in Result_OnHold);
RemoveIf(SC_OnCommsHold, IsEmpty(Filter(Master_Transaction_Log, Scan_Code = Result_OnHold, Transaction_Type="New Equipment Delivery - Comms Lockoff")));
```

It takes a few seconds to run, so I suspect it's actually looking through the database, but the result is that **SC_OnCommsHold** ends up with all four test codes, and that is a non-starter for the rest of everything. My little commented-out line (#3) above was my helper to make sure I was thinking right on the data structures, but the actual implementation above (line #4) fails.

I keep thinking that this line is the one kicking me, but I can't figure out what I need.

After I can get **SC_OnCommsHold** properly populated, I'm hoping to be able to use the same trick to *de*populate those elements from **SC_Remainder_1**.

-=-=-=-=-

I'm *really* struggling with this...

I start with a collection: **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList**

It looks like this:

```
Result
REQ1991799.RITM2280596.01 
REQ2048874.RITM2349401.01 
REQ2037354.RITM2335400.01
```

I have a database table:
**Master_Transaction_Log**

...which has three particular columns of interest:

```
Timestamp
Scan_Code
Transaction_Type
```

I would like to end up with *TWO* collections:

```
SC_ReturnToDepot
Result
REQ1991799.RITM2280596.01 

SC_Remainder_1
Result
REQ2048874.RITM2349401.01 
REQ2037354.RITM2335400.01
```

The criteria is as follows: for any given Result in **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList**, if:

A database record has Scan_Code = Result *AND* Transaction_Type = "New Equipment Delivery - Cust. Msg: Equipment Returning to Depot" *AND* Timestamp > 72 hours ago, then that value of Result is added to **SC_ReturnToDepot**

**SC_Remainder_1** are *all remaining values* that do not fit the above criteria.

I got as far as this so far, but it's killin' me after this:

```
            ClearCollect(SC_ReturnToDepot,
              ForAll(ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList,
                ...?
              );
            );

            ClearCollect(SC_Remainder_1,
              ForAll(ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList,
                ...?
              );
            );
```

I have a feeling if I can just nail that *one single line of code*, I am off to the races, but this is just... ugh, my brain is being a jerk.

-=-=-=-=-=-

Clarifications

- This is part of a many-steps cascading process that starts with
  **ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList**
- I am not in a position where I'm able to change the data on the SQL table, nor can I switch
  all my logic structure over to doing it all in Stored Procedures,
  etc.
- If there was a way in PowerApps to send a specific SQL query,
  and that specific SQL query would produce the right results in a
  Collection, then I'm open to that, but the result has to be the
  Collection as described above, because I use these resultant Collections to
  feed other processes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways in which you can go about this scenario. You can create each collection with two Filter expressions, where the condition of the second one is the negation of the first, something along the lines of

```
ClearCollect(
  SC_ReturnToDepot,
  Filter(
    Master_Transaction_Log,
    Scan_Code in ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList,
      And Transaction_Type = "New Equipment Delivery - Cust. Msg: Equipment Returning to Depot"
      And Timestamp > DateAdd(Now(), -3, TimeUnit.Days)));
ClearCollect(
  SC_Remainder_1,
  Filter(
    Master_Transaction_Log,
    Not(
      Scan_Code in ScanDataCollection_SmartComm_MasterList,
        And Transaction_Type = "New Equipment Delivery - Cust. Msg: Equipment Returning to Depot"
        And Timestamp > DateAdd(Now(), -3, TimeUnit.Days))));
```

Another option would be to use a ForAll expression and for each record, use an If expression to insert into one of the two collections, similar to the formula below:

```
Clear(SC_ReturnToDepot);
Clear(SC_Remainder_1);
ForAll(
  Master_Transaction_Log,
  If(
    Scan_Code in Master_Transaction_Log
      And Transaction_Type = "New Equipment Delivery - Cust. Msg: Equipment Returning to Depot"
      And Timestamp > DateAdd(Now(), -3, TimeUnit.Days),
    Collect(SC_ReturnToDepot, ThisRecord),
    Collect(SC_Remainder_1, ThisRecord)))
```

Comment: Hm, I may have accidentally included an ambiguity. I want to be sure that my search is "for every item in my collection, look for it on the database" as opposed to "for every item in the database, look for it in my collection." The difference is important because the database has over half a million entries. I'll edit accordingly...

Comment: I was able to allllmost get a solution running based on your second suggestion, but it broke down on the compound lookup (see Edit #2 above).

Comment: And the compound lookup is absolutely critical in this workflow.